# php mysql move selected tag

Tags: php, html, mysql

In my Database I have this column called className which contains a piece of text that should decide it's color.

It's names like this bgm-orange, bgm-red, bgm-teal etc.

```
<div class="event-tag" name="color" id="color">
       <span data-tag="bgm-teal" class="bgm-teal selected"></span>
       <span data-tag="bgm-orange" class="bgm-orange"></span>
       <span data-tag="bgm-red" class="bgm-red"></span>
</div>
```

What I want is to move the "selected" tag to what information it gets from the className column to the specific productid in the database.

productid 1 is might bgm-orange so it moves the selected tag to bgm-orange.
productid 2 is might bgm-orange so it moves the selected tag to bgm-red etc.

Hope there is someone that can help me with this

Comment: Could you be more clear. You understand php? What decides the productid?

Comment: productid is decided in a $_GET['id]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u want something like this:

```
<div class="event-tag" name="color" id="color">
       <span data-tag="bgm-teal" class="bgm-teal <?php if($product['className']=='bgm-teal'){echo "selected"; }?>"></span>
       <span data-tag="bgm-orange" class="bgm-orange <?php if($product['className']=='bgm-orange'){echo "selected"; }?>"></span>
       <span data-tag="bgm-red" class="bgm-red <?php if($product['className']=='bgm-red'){echo "selected"; }?>"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't know why I didn't thought about that solution!